# How to update a database date-field to sysdate with BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I created an interface that updates a few database fields without issue (Oracle, so I am using a wcf-custom send receive port).

It all works fine until i actually try to update a date field. ideally, I should update it to an sysdate but since the data is send as text this is impossible.

The following query works and is what my sendport should do.

```
update BT 
set LAST_UPDATE_DSTAMP = '17/01/17 14:03:35' 
where status = 'Test'
```

My interface creates the following XML that is send to the sendport

```
<Update xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/BELDBA/Table/BT">
  <RECORDSET>
    <STATUS>Complete</STATUS>
    <LAST_UPDATE_DSTAMP>18/01/17 09:36:40</LAST_UPDATE_DSTAMP>
  </RECORDSET>
  <FILTER>TRANSACTION_ID='5958106'</FILTER>
</Update>
```

But I keep getting this error:

> System.ArgumentException: ORA-1843: not a valid month

I have tried switching around where the day, month and year are (mm/dd/yy and yy/mm/dd) but i always get the not a valid month error. Does anyone have any expierience with updating the database directly in BizTalk?

Comment: Have you tried formatting it in the ISO format?  e.g. `2017-01-18T09:36:40Z`?  I believe that should work.

Comment: @DanField i just tried changing the xml so it has: <LAST_UPDATE_DSTAMP>2017-01-19T09:08:43Z</LAST_UPDATE_DSTAMP> But it still comes up with invalid month.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is that if there's a generated schema for this, check the restriction on the generated schema - it may have a regex in there that will give you some kind of hint about what format it expects.  I know the `TIME` type in a SQL Server schema expects some weird string format.